# Adding lower gears to a nine speed Ultegra road bike with triple ring

Tags: derailleur

My wife has a road bike with an Ultegra triple crank and a nine speed Ultegra 13/30 cassette. She needs a lower gear. Can the derailleur handle a larger rear sprocket? Ho large?

Comment: Are you okay to replace the derailleur with something longer-cage ?

Comment: Having a triple crank up front further limits the max tooth count in rear due to increased chain wrap.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure which version of an Ultegra derailleur you’ve got, but if it’s the 6500, it’s only rated for a 27-tooth cog and 37 teeth of wrap. You’re probably at 31 teeth of wrap.

It might be more productive to put on smaller chainrings. Depending on what she’s got now, that’ll get her an extra gear or two.

Comment: Current chain wrap is closer to max of 37 already.  17 rear + 18 to 22 front